# Code in common.js file running twice on webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a javascript project that is using webpack to compile the code. I have a file called common.js that houses all of the scripts used across the entire site. On some page specific js files I import a function from common.js so that I can use it. Unfortunately the javascript in common.js gets run twice. Here is some sample code:

common.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Loaded");
});

export function doSomethingCool() {
    console.log("I just did something cool");
}
```

cool.js

```
import { doSomethingCool } from "../common";
doSomethingCool();
```

cool.chtml

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/cool.js"></script>
```

notcool.cshtml

```
<!-- There isn't any special script on this page -->
```

The expected output for cool.js is:

```
"Loaded"
"I just did something cool"
```

Instead I am getting:

```
"Loaded"
"Loaded"
"I just did something cool"
```

notcool.js is behaving as expected by outputting:

```
"Loaded"
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't see why the `document.ready` event would fire twice unless you are navigating to different individual html pages. I also don't see why you would be using that event as it couples your otherwise simple module to the DOM for no reason.

Comment: cool.html and notcool.html are different pages.